# Difference between subspace types?

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

What is the difference between unstable and center subspace? To my knowledge, **stable subspace** is defined by Eigen vectors where its real part of Eigen values $\mathrm{Re}\,\lambda < 0$.

**Unstable subspace** is a linear span of those Eigen vectors where $\mathrm{Re}\,\lambda > 0$.

**Center subspace** - this is where I'm not sure. Is is possible to consider center subspace to be a linear span of those vectors where all $\mathrm{Re}\,\lambda = 0$ or $\mathrm{Re}\,\lambda > 0$ and imaginary part $\mathrm{Im}\,\lambda \neq 0$?

**Example:**

Let's say I have these 3 Eigen vectors $\left(\lambda_1 = 2,\:\: \lambda_1 = i,\:\: \lambda_3 = -i \right)$:

$\begin{equation} W_1 = (0,0,1) \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: \textrm{where}\: \textbf{real part:}\:\: U_1 = (0,0,1)  \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\: \textrm{and}\: \textbf{imaginary part:}\:\: V_1 = (0,0,0)\,i  \\ W_2 = (i,1,0) \\ W_3 = (-i,1,0) \:\:\: \end{equation}$

I understand that unstable subspace is

$E^{U}=\mathrm{span}\{W_1\}$,

because $\mathrm{Re}\,\lambda_1 = 2 > 0$ and $z$ axis $\neq 0$. However, how is it possible that center subspace is

$E^{C}=\mathrm{span}\{U_2,V_2\}$,

and not stable subspace as well - does the imaginary part that is greater than $0$ makes the difference?

Also, how is it possible that $W_3$ doesn't create any subspace at all (at least, I haven't found $W_3$ in the results)?

Thanks

Comment: You seem to be a little confused. You only care about real and imaginary parts of the eigen*values*, not the eigen*vectors*.

Comment: I admit that I'm a bit confused, that's why I asked for a short help. However, in case of unstable subspace - I know that it is defined by eigenvectors as well - $x,y=0$ would suggest that plane xy is not unstable and $z=1$ defines the $z$ axis to be unstable...